# how can I send data from another page by post to bulk domain search page in whmcs?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, whmcs

I have created a page containing a text-area field and few check boxes, from where user can write many domain names in each line in text-area field, and then can choose different domain type through check-boxes. then user clicks on submit button which is redirected to bulk domain search page ?
Link to page where I'm trying to do this is --
http://www.ailogica.com/wp/packages/

I tried to create a simple submit button, but that does not work, then I wrote following code to submit the data by calling a function --

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function alerttlds() {
    jQuery.noConflict();
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    var values = new Array();
    var tld = new Array();
    var bulkdomains = new Array;
    jQuery.each(jQuery("input[name='tld[]']:checked"), function() {
        tld[j++] = jQuery(this).val();
    });
    for(var k = 0; k < tld.length; k++) {
        var lines = jQuery('textarea[name=sld]').val().split('\n');
        jQuery.each(lines, function(){
            bulkdomains[i++] = this+tld[k];
        });
    }
    //alert(bulkdomains.join("\n"));
    document.getElementById('bulkdomains').value = bulkdomains.join("\n");
    document.forms["bulkchecks"].submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: please add the html code, so I can test it

Comment: Why don't you do everything on server side?

Comment: @schnawel007--- you can check the above link...and view page source. you will find exactly the same source code as I have written.